# is it possible to make a connection between Outlook and SharePoint list

Tags: document-library, outlook

I just want all the emails can be listed into the sharepoint lists, like document library.
and solution can help?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can definitely do it...Here are links for [2007](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2007/09/28/sharepoint-outlook-the-perfect-link.aspx)  and  [2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/synchronize-sharepoint-2010-content-with-outlook-2010-HA101881295.aspx)

Comment: You can mark it an answer if it helped you...read more about community FAQs at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking on how incoming emails are to be stored in SharePoint lists or libraries.

You can establish this using some changes on SMTP settings and allowing the SharePoint list to accept incoming emails as items.

Please check this msdn article on how this is done - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvagan/archive/2008/01/26/incoming-email-configuration-moss.aspx